# fix an auto-complete-mode and linum-mode annoyance

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm using `auto-complete-mode` which I think is totally fantastic.  I'm also a big fan of `linum-mode` but I've got a very irritating issue when the two are used together, especially when I'm working in a new buffer (or a buffer with very few lines).

Basically the buffer is 'x' lines long but when auto-complete kicks in it "adds" lines to the buffer, so `linum-mode` keeps switching, for example, between displaying line numbers on one column or two columns, depending on whether `auto-complete` is suggesting a completion or not.

So you type a sentence and you see your buffer's content frantically shifting from left to right at every keypress.  It is *really* annoying.

I take it the solution involves configuring the *linum-format* variable but I don't know how.

Ideally it would be great if my linum-format was:

- dynamic
- right-aligned
- considering there are 'y' more lines to the buffer than what the buffer actually has

My rationale being that `auto-complete` shall not suggest more than 'y' suggestion and that, hence, the two shall start playing nicely together.

For example, if 'y' is set to 20 and my buffer has 75 lines, then linum should use two columns: because no matter where I am `auto-complete` shall not make the buffer 'bigger' than 99 lines.

On the contrary, if 'y' is still set to 20 and my buffer has 95 lines, then `linum` should use three columns because otherwise if I'm near the end of the buffer and `auto-complete` kicks in my buffer shall start "wobbling" left and right when I type.

I'd rather not hardcode "3 columns wide" for `linum`.

I guess using "dynamic but always at least two columns" would somehow fix most annoyances but still something as I described would be great.

*P.S: I realize that my 'fix' would imply that linum would always display on at least two columns, and I'm fine with that... As long as it stays right-aligned and use 2, 3 or 4 columns depending on the need.*

Answer (score 13):

Simply put the following line in .emacs which resolves this issue. It is in auto-complete.el.

```
(ac-linum-workaround)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've written a couple of previous answers on modifying the linum-mode output, which you could probably adapt to your purposes.

- [Relative Line Numbers In Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874516/relative-line-numbers-in-emacs/6928112#6928112)
- [Colorize current line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591334/colorize-current-line-number/10593165#10593165)

**Edit:** Here's the most basic version of that code (also on [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers), albeit somewhat buried), which doesn't modify the default output at all, but uses the techniques from those other answers to be more efficient than the default code. That's probably a more useful starting point for you.

```el
(defvar my-linum-format-string "%4d")

(add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook 'my-linum-get-format-string)

(defun my-linum-get-format-string ()
  (let* ((width (length (number-to-string
                         (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))))
         (format (concat "%" (number-to-string width) "d")))
    (setq my-linum-format-string format)))

(setq linum-format 'my-linum-format)

(defun my-linum-format (line-number)
  (propertize (format my-linum-format-string line-number) 'face 'linum))
```

Comment: +1 thanks...  I'm only beginning with Lisp dialects (already solved near one hundred of the 4clojure problems so I'm slowly starting to get a least the basics of Lisp -- even if Clojure is not the most typical Lisp)... I can already understand some of your code but my elisp-fu is not very strong (these hooks etc. are all pretty alien to me).  I'll try to hack-modify your code to fix my issue that said : )

Answer (score 2):

Just have the same problem, after seeing 'patching the source' I believe it could be done with `advice`. Here is what I come up with

```
(defadvice linum-update
  (around tung/suppress-linum-update-when-popup activate)
  (unless (ac-menu-live-p)
    ad-do-it))
```

I would like to use `popup-live-p` as mentioned but unfortunately it requires the variable for the popup, which we couldn't know in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
I ended up patching the source for linum.el. I added an extra hook that runs before updates.

Here's the patched file: [linum.el (github)](https://github.com/chrisbarrett/.emacs.d/blob/7e6f203f6aec47b33ad510672ed62e7f4f096d87/packs/dev/colour-pack/lib/linum.el)

Here's the code I have in my init.el:

```lisp
;; Load custom linum.
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/linum.el")

;; Suppress line number updates while auto-complete window
;; is displayed.
(add-hook 'linum-before-update-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (when auto-complete-mode
               (if (ac-menu-live-p)
                   (setq linum-suppress-updates t)
                 (setq linum-suppress-updates nil)))))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You could replace `ac-menu-live-p` with `popup-live-p` to make this work with anything that uses popup.el to show menus. Haven't tested that though.

Comment: Gutted, looks like this reduces the number of updates, but any action that makes the autocomplete menu redraw will update the line numbers.

Comment: Looking at the source, Linum looks at the `window-end` C function to calculate the number of lines, so a workaround is beyond my ken. If you're happy patching the source, you could declare a global var, eg. `(defvar linum-suppress nil)`, and add that to the test in the `linum-update` function in linum.el. You could then freely enable or disable the updates in your hooks. This feels dirty though.